# My kernel keeps dying in jupyter notebook when i run fit function

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

My kernel keeps dying when i run fit function
my tensorflow version 2.6.0

i've reinstalled the jupyter notebook, upgraded my pip, upgraded my tensoflow library,
added this line

```
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
```

and still my kernel keeps dying

this is the code i tried to run

```
learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = 'val_acc', patience = 3, verbose = 1, factor = .5, min_lr = .00001)

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_categorical_accuracy', patience = 4)

print('====')

history = model.fit_generator(generator = train_batches, steps_per_epoch = train_batches.n//batch_size, epochs=epochs, 
                    validation_data = val_batches, validation_steps = val_batches.n//batch_size, verbose = 0,
                    callbacks = [learning_rate_reduction, es])
```

Comment: There's a good chance it's dying due to running out of memory. It's impossible to say more without knowing details about the model, data, the system being used, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you should try one of these

1. Check Environment Variables

   - make sure you have `CUDA_PATH`
   - make sure you write path to `cuda/bin`, `cuda/include`, `cuda/lib/x64` in `PATH` in `System Variables`
2. Check if the model is too complex by training the network on smaller simpler model
3. Make sure anaconda navigator is updated
4. In my experience python 3.8.5 and tensorflow 2.7 works and can be downloaded in the environments in anaconda navigator

Answer (score 1):

If it broke with simple model, it means you're doing something wrong with the PATH in system environment
If you're using VSCode you might have to set all the variables first before using
If you're using Anaconda you can download directly in download section
im using tensorflow 2.8 and python 3.10 and still works